# Flash movie stopped loading xml after flash update

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I am loading a flash movie that calls another that calls an XML file. It used to work fine until the recent flash player updates. Now i am at a loss of how to get it working. Seems to load everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the action script calling the XML

```
    var feedMovie;
 //load the XML data
 mein_xml = new XML();
 mein_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
 mein_xml.load("data.xml");
 mein_xml.onLoad = function(status) {
    if (status) {
        content_xml = mein_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
        PhotoLoaderMC.loadMovie(content_xml[0].attributes.MapImage);
        delete mein_xml;
        initMenu();
    }
 };

    // via this function, we set the detail's points position according to XML X&Y values
 function SetPoints() {
    var j = 0;
    for (i=item; i<maxItems; i++) {
        nName = "PointerMC"+j;
        attachMovie("PointerMC", nName, j++);
        if (content_xml[i] != undefined) {
            this[nName]._y = content_xml[i].attributes.PY;
            this[nName]._x = content_xml[i].attributes.PX;
            this[nName].num.text = i+1;
            this[nName].id_txt.text = content_xml[i].attributes.id;
            this[nName].onPress = function() {
                    _global.detailMCClose = false;
                    daten = content_xml[this.num.text-1];
                    // this calls the detailMC for each detail point.
                    if (daten.attributes.PartID == "Image") {
                        attachMovie("detailMC-Image", "detailMCImage", 1000);
                        detailMCImage._alpha = 90;
                        detailMCImage._visible = true;
                        detailMCImage._x = 240;
                        detailMCImage._y = 200;
                        detailMCImage.photo = daten.attributes.photo;
                        detailMCImage.DescMC.desc.htmlText = daten.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                        detailMCImage.onEnterFrame = function() {
                            if (detailMCClose) {
                                removeMovieClip("detailMCImage");
                                _global.detailMCClose = false;
                            }
                        };
                        // this close detailMC for Image!
                        detailMCImage.CloseButton.onPress = function() {
                            _global.detailMCClose = true;
                        };
                    }
                    if (daten.attributes.PartID == "Movie") {
                        attachMovie("detailMC-Movie", "detailMCMovie", 1000);
                        detailMCMovie._alpha = 100;
                        detailMCMovie._visible = true;
                        detailMCMovie._x = 200;
                        detailMCMovie._y = 200;
                        detailMCMovie.feedMovie = daten.attributes.movie;
                        detailMCMovie.DescMC.desc.htmlText = daten.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                        detailMCMovie.onEnterFrame = function() {
                            if (detailMCClose) {
                                removeMovieClip("detailMCMovie");
                                _global.detailMCClose = false;
                            }
                        };
                        // this close detailMC for Movie!
                        detailMCMovie.CloseButton.onPress = function() {
                            _global.detailMCClose = true;
                        };
                    }
            };
        }
    }
 }
 function initMenu() {
    numbers = content_xml.length;
    max = content_xml.length;
    maxItems = content_xml.length;
    item = 0;
 }
```

And here is a sample of the XML file. I have tried adding in allow domain etc.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <contents>

        <Item PartID="Image" PX="570"  PY="240" photo="/images/network/FlashMap/centers/UH.gif" MapImage="/images/network/FlashMap/image/Counties.png" Number="1">
            <details>
                <![CDATA[<b><font size="+1" color="#ffffff">University of Houston SBDC <br>2302 Fannin, Suite 200 <br>Houston, TX 77002 <br>713-752-8444<br>Third Ward:   713-520-7303<br></font></b><br><a href="http://www.sbdc.uh.edu" target="_blank">www.sbdc.uh.edu</a><br><br>Counties served: Harris-East End, Fifth   Ward and Third Ward]]></details>
        </Item>

        <Item PartID="Image" PX="675"  PY="40" photo="/images/network/FlashMap/centers/angelina.jpg" Number="2">
            <details><![CDATA[<b><font size="+1" color="#ffffff">Angelina College SBDC, Lufkin<br>3500 South First St. <br>Lufkin, TX   75901-1768 <br>936-633-5400<br><br></font></b><br><a href="http://www.angelina.cc.tx.us/" target="_blank">www.angelina.cc.tx.us </a><br><br>Counties served: Angelina, Polk, Trinity, Tyler]]></details>
        </Item>

</content>
```

Comment: your sample xml has an error <contents> and ends with </content> should be </contents>

Comment: This code is AS2 not AS3

Comment: Thanks for catching the xml error. I have fixed but still does not work or load the xml.

Comment: add event listeners and and `try..catch` around `load()` to catch any security or io errors

Comment: AS2 code should still run under the new player. Ours does. But I believe we're using a different method to load our XML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Still cant get it working and at a loss. Any suggestions on how i could change the xml call? Sorry but pretty new to this or new AGAIN since it has been so long since i have worked with flash.